# Get servers list from New relic API using php

Tags: php, curl, newrelic

I try to get data from New Relic API using CURL php

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/servers.json' \
     -H 'X-Api-Key:my-api-key' -i \
```

i write

```
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.newrelic.com/v2/servers.json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['X-Api-Key' => 'my-api-key']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump($data);
```

but it not work and write `403  New Relic API access has not been enabled` what i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello your all do right but header your send wrong. it must be next

```
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.newrelic.com/v2/servers.json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['X-Api-Key:my-api-key']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump($data);
```

if your `my-api-key` is real API key :)

Answer (score 1):

If 'my-api-key' is not a substitution for your API key then replace it with the API key.  If it IS, then verify that it really is the api key and not the license key or the data access key.   The API key is probably not activated and you can check it by going to 
https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/ACCOUNT_NUMBER/integrations?page=data_sharing
(replace ACCOUNT_NUMBER with your acount id number).

Here is a working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

//Your New Relic API key
$api_key = "1234abcd1234";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/servers.json',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true, // Instead of the "-i" flag,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("X-Api-Key:".$api_key)
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl); 
print_r($resp)
?>
```